# Eloquent relation output in view, undefined offset 0

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am currently coding a project in laravel 4, and I am trying to echo out some eloquent data as part of a search function I am building.

Now, my problem is: When I try to get a value from another table (which the main table has a many to many relation with) I keep getting an error that says undefined offset 0, what's weird though is that the same code worked only a couple of minutes ago... (I added some stuff, then ctrl+z'ed all the way back to the "working" one, which now conjures up the same error)

Controller.php

```
public function getData()
    {

    $data = Routine::with('measurements')->get();


        return View::make('sok')
        ->with('title', 'Søk')
        ->with('data', $data);
    }
```

View.blade.php

```
@if(isset($data))
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Tittel</td>
                <td>Verdi</td>
                <td>Ansatt ID</td>
            </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->measurements[0]->title }}</td> //This be the one that errors
                <td>{{ $data->value }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->emp_id }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
    @endif
```

I am currently at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post a var_dump of $data?

Comment: Part of the var_dump: http://imgur.com/AG2eD7p

Was way too long to just copy paste, but essentially it was the same thing down a dozen times with +1 on the index.

Comment: what about if you var_dump($data->measurements)?

Comment: var_dump($data->measurements);

ErrorException

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$measurements

Comment: It sounds like there aren't any routines that have measurements.  It could be why it was working before and not now.

Comment: Then you should see my answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I don't get. I have data in the tables, and a query like "SELECT * FROM routines, measurements, measure_routine WHERE routines.id = measure_routine.routine_id AND measure_routine.measure_id = measurements.id" works just fine in the DB.

Comment: Post your models and migrations

Answer (score 1):

In your view:

```
@if(isset($data))
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Tittel</td>
                <td>Verdi</td>
                <td>Ansatt ID</td>
            </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $data)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
                <td>
                @if($data->measurements->count()>0)
                    {{ $data->measurements->first()->title }}
                @endif
                </td>
                <td>{{ $data->value }}</td>
                <td>{{ $data->emp_id }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </table>
    @endif
```

Comment: worked for me, it always showed `undefined index 0`, after using count, it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar bug. The error message is not helpful at all. My issue turned out to be a typo, in that i had forgotten to pass a parameter to my 'where' function, ie

```
$event = $this->events->make()->whereSlug()->first();
```

So the bottom line is, go through your query with a fine toothcomb and check that it's definitely retrieving records before worrying about relationships.

Answer (score -1):

`measurements` would be a collection, not an array, so trying to get the first value of it with `$data->measurements[0]->title` will not work.

Instead, try, `$data->measurements->first()->title`

Edit:  After doing some testing, either way will work.

Using `$data->measurements()->first()->title;` with no data available will result in `Trying to get property of non-object`

Using `$data->measurements[0]->title;` will result in `Undefined offset: 0`

It would seem as though whichever data you are working with is not valid.  You may need to manually check your database to be sure there is data in there and the data makes sense.

`clod's` answer should work.  If you are expecting there to always be results, it would be best to use `has()` rather than `where()`

Comment: that will do, but remember that it might return an error if there are no measurements

Comment: Hey, tried that, it threw me an exception with Trying to get property of non-object, but like I said it worked with measurements[0] earlier, and now suddenly it does not.